# Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established in Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I added Spring Kafka to my Spring application and expected it to work, but I got

```less
INFO     [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.1
INFO --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8a516edc2755df89
INFO --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1694915576434
INFO --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
WARN --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established.
```

I added it to my `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

and configured it

```java
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic checkInTopic() {
    return new NewTopic(checkInTopicName, 1, (short) 1);
}
```

where `bootstrapAddress` is configured via `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:  
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

and I also have a producer config:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    ));
}
```

What's wrong? Should I run Kafka somehow manually on localhost port `9092`? I assume it's done automatically by Spring framework just as I don't have to deploy it on tomcat because it's bundled. Does it start Kafka service or should I do it myself?

Comment: Yes, you have to install and start your Kafka instance aside. The `spring-kafka` artifact only has the API, not the whole Kafka itself.

Comment: Was there missing documentation that says Kafka shouldn't be ran first? Are you following a specific tutorial? How can this be made clear for others assuming the same?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am following the Baeldung's introduction https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka. In the section 3 there is a mention of a terminal command *Previously, we ran command-line tools to create topics in Kafka*, but I couldn't see any link to a previous lesson, so I got confused. This is the first link after searching for *spring add kafka*. I clicked on the 3rd as well https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview, but it also doesn't seem to mention that. Only in the 2nd link https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-kafka/ I can find quickstart https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.

Comment: First sentence of section 2 talks about downloading and installing Kafka before doing anything with maven/Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to run Kafka manually on localhost port `9092`.

The `spring-kafka` module contains the Kafka APIs which is needed to do operations on Kafka topics, producers and consumers.

**Note:** Spring-Kafka module does come with **Embedded Kafka** but that can only be used for **Spring Kafka based test classes** via the annotation [@EmbeddedKafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/test/context/EmbeddedKafka.html). See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing) for example on how to write Kafka test classes with that annotation.

That's the reason why you need to setup/install a live running Kafka instance on your local for your application to connect and use it.

**Now, it completely depends on your use case. See which use case suits you better.**

---

On the other hand, you will need to download and setup Apache Kafka on your system.

There are 2 options to run a Kafka service: with legacy **Zookeeper** and newer **KRaft**.

[KRaft mode is more scalable than ZooKeeper mode, allowing Kafka clusters to handle more traffic and data. KRaft mode is faster than ZooKeeper mode, resulting in lower latency and higher throughput.](https://romanglushach.medium.com/the-evolution-of-kafka-architecture-from-zookeeper-to-kraft-f42d511ba242)

Initial steps are the same.

1. Download the latest version of Kafka from [here](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads).
2. Navigate to `bin/` in the kafka directory.

## KRaft

Steps continued:

3. Build the project using `./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.10`
4. Generate a Cluster UUID
   `KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(./kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"`
5. Format Log Directories
   `./kafka-storage.sh format -t $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID -c ../config/kraft/server.properties`
6. Modify the `log.dirs` to point to some other valid directory instead of `/tmp/kraft-combined-logs`.
7. Start the Kafka broker.
   `./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/kraft/server.properties`

For Windows, there is a folder `windows` with batch scripts corresponding to Linux/Mac shell scripts.

## Zookeeper

Steps continued:

3. Start the **Zookeeper**.

   - Linux/Mac: `./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties`
   - Windows: `windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties`
4. Edit the **server.properties**

   - Uncomment this line of code : `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` to enable broker to be listened at this socket.
   - Modify the `log.dirs` to point to some other valid directory instead of `/tmp/kafka-logs`.
5. Start the Kafka broker.

   - Linux/Mac: `./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties`
   - Windows: `windows\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties`

That's all for initial setup.

---

Visit [here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) to read more info on topic creation and other things related to Kafka.

Now, Spring application will be able to connect to Kafka.

Comment: Latest Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper and default listeners setting is fine. `log.dirs` should be changed to not use /tmp

Comment: @OneCricketeer Oh! Then why kafka still has those zookeeper script? Just wondering..

Comment: @AnishB. It turns out that Kafka is in the ongoing process of migrating from Zookeeper to KRaft. KRaft is more scalable and faster than Zookeeper. I will edit the answer so that it shows the way to use KRaft as well, because we want to encourage people to use KRaft instead of legacy Zookeeper.

Comment: The scripts will be there until Kafka 4.0, when it's completely removed. There will be a migration period. Also, EmbeddedKafka is part of Spring-kafka, so technically is does come with Kafka binaries, at least for testing purposes, but could also try to be used as an embedded broker/durable message bus, I guess

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but after researching this problem, I concluded to declare the configuration class by defining the EmbeddedKafkaBroker.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") 
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedKafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker() {
        return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1).kafkaPorts(9092);
    }
}
```

by using this solution we could run embedded Kafka at the integration test phase without annotating all integration test classes.

I used the maven plugin for operating my integration tests.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>

            <configuration>
                <profiles>test</profiles>
                <wait>1000</wait>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wait>1000</wait>
        <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How would you annotate the test classes instead of using the embedded kafka broker? Why did you add wait to your maven execution configuration?

Comment: I annotated only over the testing method at the IntegraionTest Scenario. By using the EmbeddedKafkaConfig I was able to start the Embedded Kafka at the pre-integration-test. Additionally, you will need to add the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092 inside of application-test.properties file.

Comment: ```  
/**
 * The number of milli-seconds to wait between each attempt to check if the spring
 * application is ready.
 */
@Parameter
private long wait = 500;

/**
 * The maximum number of attempts to check if the spring application is ready.
 * Combined with the "wait" argument, this gives a global timeout value (30 sec by
 * default)
 */
@Parameter
private int maxAttempts = 60;   
```

Comment: By using the mentioned scenario, you won't need to use @EmbeddedKafka annotation.